# glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES) doesn't render anything

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to import .obj files but cant even get a triangle rendered.  Here is what I'm trying to do just to test if it can show something.

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(1, 1, 1);
    glVertex3f(2, 2, 2);
glEnd();
```

This doesn't display anything.  However when I change GL_TRIANGLES for GL_LINES it displays the line.

How can I get the triangle to display?

Language: C++

OS: Mac 10.7.3

Comment: First of all, your points lay on a line. You might wanna think about that.

Comment: Good point, my mistake to be coding so late...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A triangle where all three points are colinear (in the same line) has zero area. And a triangle renderer only renders the *area* of a triangle, not the edges of it. So it renders zero pixels.